# Prove the statements.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

[image]

> Prove that,

- *f(x)*=0 when *k* is not prime
- *f(x)*=1 when *k* is prime
- N.B: Here *f(x)= a mod k* means the reminder we get by dividing 'a' by 'k'

*I found that the statements are right by testing those. But I am not understanding how to prove that. So, I need help.*

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Did you mean in your N.B that _a_ is the remainder of division of _f(x)_ by _k_?

Comment: You may want to read about Wolstenholme theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Every term in $a$ is the ratio of $(2k-1!)$ over an integer $i\in[1,2k-1]$. Hence taking the modulo $k$, all terms vanish, but

$$\frac{(2k-1)!}k=1\cdot2\cdots(k-1)\cdot(k+1)\cdots(2k-1).$$

If $k$ is composite, the above product will contain the factors of $k$, and the modulo also vanishes.

Remains to prove the value $1$ for a prime. (Wilson's theorem.)

Comment: Can you please explain how can I prove the value 1 for a prime using Wilson's theorem?

Comment: @Mathematician: did you lookup this theorem ?

Comment: p-1!=-1(mod p) ..where p is prime. I understood that @yves Daoust

Comment: @Mathematician: just compare to the product in my answer ($\bmod k$)

Comment: What is modulo K? @yves Daoust

Comment: @Mathematician: are you serious ?

Comment: I mean is (mod K) and modulo K same?...please don't mind..I just learned about this a few days ago.

Comment: @Mathematician: didn't you read your own question ?

Comment: Yes... here is told mod k... Which means dividing something by k.. ain't I correct?..does modulo K mean that? @yves Daoust

Comment: @Mathematician: I don't see any "modulo" written in what you posted. But of course, "mod" is shorthand.